# CORS Error in socket.io when using NodeJS / Express and HTTPS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using the below code to be able to access socket.io from different parts of my app. All works fine on the dev server but once i go and try it in production on an HTTPS server it fails with the following error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://nodejs.demo.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MkQBnlU' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9999' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute

In my app.js file I start it like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const io = require('sio').init(https);

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/nodejs.demo.net.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/ServerCertificate.cer')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443,()=>{
  console.log("listening secure via SSL on 443")
})
```

and here is the content of the sio file

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');
let io;

module.exports = {
   init: function(server) {
        if (io) {
            throw new Error("socket.io already initialized");
        }
        // initalize socket.io to this server
        io = socketio(server);

        // put other socket.io initialization code here

        return io;
   }
   get: function() {
        if (!io) {
             throw new Error("socket.io has not yet been initialized");
        }
        return io;
   }
}
```

So where and how do I fix the cor's error?

Answer (score 0):

Your server should allow CORS requests, try the [CORS module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors):

```
// Enable All CORS Requests
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

With your code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const io = require('sio').init(https);
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/nodejs.demo.net.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/ServerCertificate.cer')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443,()=>{
  console.log("listening secure via SSL on 443")
})
```